# Why are Electromagnetism, Strong & Weak Nuclear and Gravitational Forces different?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, nuclear-physics

If they are different then why the only thing that we 'see' in them, and that identifies them, the so called 'force' as we call and see it, is same among them all.

Comment: Your question is not clear currently as it stands. However, theories are trying to unify all these forces together.. electromagnetism and the weak force have already been merged into the [electroweak force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction)... The [GUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory) tries to unite electroweak w/ the strong force, and the creation of a [TOE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything) would unify all the forces...

Comment: Curiously, yogurt, steak and a sandwich can each satisfy my hunger, yet are different.

Comment: @KyleKanos Good one! But yogurt, streak and sandwich are all made up of atoms (albeit a large qty of carbon atoms) and these atoms are in turn made up of protons, neutrons and electrons. Looks like they are indeed same in the end ;)

Comment: Likewise, we *suspect* that the forces are one & the same (TanMath mentions this), but what we *see* are very different.

Answer (score 2):

This is an area of much research. Scientist are currently trying to combine all the four forces of nature into one force.

Actually, this has been done before. Before there were five forces- electric force, magnetic force, weak force, strong force, and gravity. However, scientists like Maxwell and Faraday came along and showed that electric and magnetic forces could be combined into one force, the electromagnetic force. Also, the electromagnetic force has been combined with the weak force, leading to the electroweak force (although there is still some debate, it is widely accepted by scientists that these two forces are really one).

The [Grand Unified Theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory) tries to unite the electroweak force with the strong force while the [Theory of Everything](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything) combines *all* forces into one. The idea is that at extremely high temperatures and energies, like at the beginning of the universe, all the forces were one, but as the the temperatures decreased, the forces seperated into the main four forces.

This is a field of ongoing research and I hope those wikipedia links are helpful.

Comment: Point of order: the electric and magnetic interactions were unified prior to the discovery of the nuclear forces.